# content added to parsys displays outside of containing html. How can I get it to show inside it?

Tags: css, xml, jsp, aem

I'm trying to create an adobe cq component and include a parsys element that users can drag other components into. However, when I drag items into my parsys component they always display outside of the html tags I wrapped around my include. What am I doing wrong?

**html in my component jsp**

```
<div class="div-one">
    div one
</div>
<div class="div-two">
     <cq:include path="par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
</div>
```

**content.xml for my component**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:description=""
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="title"
    sling:resourceSuperType="foundation/components/parbase"
    allowedParents="[*/parsys]"
    componentGroup="My Group"
    cq:htmlTag=""/>
```

**How the html is rendered in a browser after I think I dragged a component into div-two**

```
<div class="div-one">
    div one
</div>
<div class="div-two">
     <cq:include path="par" resourcetype="foundation/components/parsys">
</cq:include></div>
<div id="myComponent" class="row">
</div>
```

Comment: If you have any component that have parsys inside it as you have in "div-two" and any component you drop inside that parsys also will be inside "div-two". If your component's divs are not under "div-two" then you are not adding the component to the parsys you added under "div-two".

Comment: Can you post your CSS?  The styles you use on the DIVs and other tags could explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`cq:include` is a tag library element which should not appear in the rendered HTML.

Make sure to include global.jsp at the top of each JSP file when using the CQ taglib:

```
<%@ include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp" %>
```

For more on the CQ taglib see [this doc](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/components.html#CQ%20Tag%20Library).